# A question about random element

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$ from $(Ω,F)$ to $(S,B)$，where $(Ω,F)$ and $(S,B)$ are both measurable spaces, how can I show that $$\{ w:X(w) \ne Y(w)\} \in F$$

When 
$(S,B)＝(R，\mathcal{B})$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$ algebra of the real line, I know how to do it. But I don't know how to deal with the general case.

Hope for your help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this is not true. Take for example the space $\Omega = S = \{1,2 \}$ and  $F = B = \{ \Omega, \varnothing \}$.

Then define

\begin{align*}
 X(1) &= 1, \ \ & Y(1)  = 1 \\
 X(2) & = 2, \ \ & Y(2) = 1
\end{align*}

These are two measurable functions, but the set $$\{ X \neq Y\} = \{ 2\} \not\in F.$$

Comment: It was very unclear (I thought it is incorrect), so I've edited this, please check.

Comment: @zhoraster you are right, it was written badly. I guess I changed the example while I was writing it. Now it looks fine.